# How to manage versioning of entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

We have an entity for which we want to save old versions as revisions, what is the best way to achieve this?

The current idea is to have two properties `Id` and `Revision` that combined makes up the primary key. I am not sure if this is the correct approach, and I have issues with how to get the database to generate the values - if I do not set them myself.

If I save a completely new entity I want both `Id` and `Revision` to be set. ´Id´ to the next id in order, and `Revision` to zero.

If I save a new version of an entity I would set the `Id` to the id of the entity I want to create a new revision of (together with all other values I might want to bring over to the new entity). I would like to leave the ´Revision´ property empty, and the database should then increment this and set it to the previous latest revision value + 1.

How can I achieve this functionality with entity framework? Can I achieve it with entity framework?

**Edit**

I have tried this setup in my `DbContext` implementation:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityDao>().HasKey(m => new { m.Id, m.Revision });
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityDao>().Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityDao>().Property(m => m.Revision).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
Only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'.
```

If I remove the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` statement on the `Revision` property, the service is able to start. But then I get an error on save since `Revision` is null - unless I manually give it a value.

There was also an issue that I could not explicitly set the `Id` property when I had the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` statement. I got the following error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Entities' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

But I found this info on how to solve that:
[explicit-values-generated-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties#explicit-values-into-sql-server-identity-columns)

Comment: Use a temporal table if you target SQL Server 2016 and later. This won't just solve the versioning problem, it will maintain proper foreign key relations as well

Comment: Temporal table sounds interesting, but I'm not sure if it is what I want. After just looking at it for 5 minutes my understanding is that a historical entity will be stored whenever an update is done. In my use case I want revisions to be created only when the user says he wants to create a new revision.

Comment: I solved it with my approach. Will write an answer tomorrow, to show how I did it. Not sure if it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

As for me the better option would be to create another versions table where you can store all of the entity versions with the entity id foreign key. And when you create completely new entity you just put it in the main table, but when you modify entity you just store existing entity inside versions table with foreign key, and update your entity in the main table. With that approach you would have the main table with only last versions of entities, so you don't need to filter them on get. And versions table from where you always can get all the versions with timestamp and some additional info that you want to have.

Comment: That could work, but then on creating a new version of an entity I would have to copy the entity from the current table to the history table and then remove it from the current and then add the new entity (with the same Id). I was hoping that it was a simpler solution. :)

Comment: you do not need to remove it from the current table just copy the entity to "history" table and update the entity in the current table =)

Comment: Yes, I though of this a bit more and I start to feel that this might be the best solution after all.

Comment: yeah, and if you have tried and preferred that approach you can mark the answer as accepted